# Confusing posting error message

Tags: virtualbox

I am wondering what is causing this error..."Your post cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network. We apologize for any inconvenience. See the help center for more."  I am literally BRAND NEW to this forum and have not even attempted to reply to anything before.  I am using a VM on Oracle VirtualBox  I don't want to get BAD reputation before I even get started here...any suggestion on what to do?  The help page doesn't really give any info on what I could have done  Thanks in advance

EDIT:  I tried, successfully from outside my VM and obviously it worked.  Is this a VM issue or did I do something else wrong?

Comment: This question would be better suited to the Meta site, but  the first question that popped into my head was whether you were using a VPN or not. There’s a remarkable amount of garbage sent via a handful of VPNs and Amazon IPs …

Comment: I don't know about this site as such but I would check what your public facing IP address is when using the VM, for example by going to: https://www.whatismyip.net/ Then check that IP against known blacklists, for example at: https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx If the VM is setup to use a specific IP that lots of other scammers/spammers also use then the IP can get blacklisted. This can also happen when using a VPN service - the VPN IP address will used by lots of other people, some of which may be doing bad stuff so the address gets blacklisted/blocked by some sites etc.

Comment: I am on a VPN actually, but switched locations before I reposted (outside of my VM)  I actually didn't even think of the VPN being the issue.  Thank you

Comment: You guys are good...Thank you for the help